# send ctrl+a message on python socket

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to send the commands using python socket.

I have to send 'ctrl+a' key stroke, first.

Typically, I connect using telnet and type 'ctrl+a' then type the enter.
In terminal 'ctrl+a' looked as '^A'.

So I tried to send using python send function like below.
s.send('^A')
But it didn't work.

It looked as '^A' on the terminal but it doesn't feel like the text.

I need to send real 'ctrl+a' message.
How can I do that?

Please advice.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

`s.send('\x01')` (Python2); `s.send(b'\x01')` (Python3).

Ctrl+A is control character with numeric value 1.